# Extract sub JSON with keys and values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have a table with a JSON TYPE column like this:

| id | json_info | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | {"Ccclaptop_model": {"value": "asus", "price": "2122"}, "laptop_ram": {"value": "6", "price": "122"}, "laptop_mouse_model": {"value": "logic", "price": "30"} , "laptop_keys_model": {"value": "USA", "price": "10"}} | 2020-02-02 |

And I'd like to have a query that extracts a sub-JSON with his key value, like this:

| id | json_info | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | {"laptop_mouse_model": {"value": "logic", "price": "30"} , "laptop_keys_model": {"value": "USA", "price": "10"}} | 2020-02-02 |

I have tried JSON_EXTRACT

```
    SELECT id,
       JSON_EXTRACT(json_info, '$.laptop_mouse_model', '$.laptop_keys_model' ) AS store_id 
FROM feature_data WHERE date = '2020-02-02';
```

but just return a JSON array without keys, like this:

| id | json_info | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | [{"value": "logic", "price": "30"} ,{"value": "USA", "price": "10"}] | 2020-02-02 |

Does somebody know if exists a function that I could use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you choose to store data in JSON format instead of normal rows and columns?

Comment: Are you sure that `WHERE date = '2020-02-02';` give you results? Because your `date` column is empty. I assume your table formatting in the question is incorrect, can you fix that?

Comment: @BillKarwin because the number of keys value may vary at any time so I only focus on update the JSON and not alter all the table

Comment: The traditional way to support that is not to add more columns. It is preferable to create a second table, and store one model per row. Then value and price would be attribute columns of that row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON_OBJECT` to combine result to a json, for example:

```
SELECT id,JSON_OBJECT('laptop_mouse_model',JSON_EXTRACT(json_info, '$.laptop_mouse_model'),'laptop_keys_model',JSON_EXTRACT(json_info, '$.laptop_keys_model')) AS store_id FROM feature_data WHERE date = '2020-02-02';
```